# Объединение блочных алгоритмов шифрования с помощью использования строки случайных бит в режиме OFB

Tags: алгоритм, криптография, шифрование

Здравствуйте.

Передо мною (студентом) была поставлена такая задача: "Запрограммировать работу объединения шифров S-AES  и S-DES с помощью использования строки случайных бит в режиме OFB".

На вход подаются два ключа K1 (для S-DES) и K2 (для S-AES) и входящее сообщение М (длинною 8 бит).

Вопросы возникли, когда я попытался объединить все эти режимы в один. У меня получился следующий алгоритм:

1. Генерация строки случайных бит R.
2. Шифрование строки случайных бит алгоритмом S-AES и получение R1.
3. Сумма по модулю 2 наборов бит R1 и M шифруется алгоритмом S-DES.
4. Сумма по модулю 2 результатов пунктов 2 и 3.
5. Сумма по модулю 2 исходного 8-битового сообщения и результата выполнения 4-ого пункта.

Именно так мною была понята схема алгоритма. Но, как я понимаю, использование строки сообщения в процессе шифрования нарушает принцип режима OFB. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие пункты надо заменить или поменять местами.

Comment: Если вы посмотрите статью "Режим шифрования" в Википедии, то увидите что зашифрованный IV ксорится с сообщением.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а скажите, пожалуйста, в таком случае необходимо строку случайных бит шифровать дважды: сперва s-des, а затем s-aes, и лишь после ксорить с входящим сообщением?

Comment: Не знаю. Вообще не понимаю зачем использовать два алгоритма.